# Почему не отображаются emoji в гитлабе?

Tags: github, gitlab, emoji

Почему на линуксе на гитлабе не отображаются емоджи? Вместо этого прямоугольники. Надо установить какой-то шрифт определённый? В доках не нашёл. На винде отображаются. На гитхабе видно и там и там.